# Distribution Convergence in PDE theory

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I'm trying to follow an Example (5.1) from a PDE book (Vasy). I was having trouble following the proof of the following question (modified):

Define a bump function: ${\delta_j}^{-n}\phi(\frac{x}{\delta_j})$ where $\phi (x) = e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}$ ($x \in [-1,1]$, 0 otherwise) and  $\lim_{j\to\infty}{\delta_j} = 0\ \ ({\delta_j} \in \mathbf{R})$. Moreover let $\psi(x)$ be any infinitely differentiable function. Show that if:
$$ u_j(\psi) = \int \delta_j^{-n} \phi(\frac{x}{\delta_j})\ \psi(x) \ dx$$ then $$\lim_{j\to\infty} u_j = c\delta_0$$ where $ c = \int\phi(x) \ dx$.

Can anyone help me understand how to show this convergence? I know I want to show that for $\forall \ \epsilon \  \exists \ J$ s.t. $\mid u_j - c\delta_0\mid<\epsilon \ \forall \ j>J$. Then what?

thanks!

Comment: in the context of distributions, $\delta$ is reserved for the Dirac

Comment: I'm just using the book notation, take it up with Vasy. (http://math.stanford.edu/~andras/)

Comment: no, you need to prove that for every test function $\psi$, $u_j(\psi) \to c \delta(\psi) = c  \psi(0)$ (that's $u_j \to \delta$ in the sense of distributions) (see [wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Distributions) : A sequence of distributions $T_k$ converges with respect to the weak-* topology on $D′(U)$ to a distribution $T$ if and only if

$\langle T_k, \varphi\rangle \to \langle T, \varphi\rangle$ for every test function $\varphi \in D(U)$ )

Comment: what does the notation $c\psi(0)$ mean? He uses this too in the second line of his proof and I got lost. So its not a limit sequence of functions in normal real analysis?

Comment: $\psi(x)$ is a test function (a bump function) : it is  $C^\infty$ and zero outside of a compact, and $\psi(0)$ is just its value at $0$. and you should write $u_j(\psi)= \int \delta_j^{-n} \phi(\frac{x}{\delta_j})\ \psi(x) \ dx$ instead of $u_j(\phi) = \ldots$

Comment: so if $support(\phi) = [-B,B]$ then $\frac{\phi(x/a_j)}{a_j}$ is zero outside of $[-a_jB,a_jB] $, i.e. it's support is smaller and smaller as $a_j \to 0$, and $u_j(\psi)= \int_{-a_jB}^{a_jB} a_j^{-1} \phi(\frac{x}{a_j})\ \psi(x) \ dx =\psi(0) \int_{-a_jB}^{a_jB} a_j^{-1} \phi(\frac{x}{a_j})\ \ dx+ \int_{-a_jB}^{a_jB} a_j^{-1} \phi(\frac{x}{a_j})(\psi(x)-\psi(0)) dx$

Comment: finally, write that $|\psi(x)-\psi(0)| < M |x| $ and voila the second term $\to 0$

Comment: @user1952009 1. so does the notation $\delta_0$ doesn't mean the first term in the sequence of \delta's (this is why you changed notation?) 2. why does n = 1 in your case, shouldn't it be general n? 3. I know that condition you wrote above is coming from the continuity of $\psi$ but I dont see how 4.Even though I defined $\phi$ to have compact support, in general it does not right? Only test functions need to be compact?

Comment: I understood nothing. yes my 1st comment was that you used $\delta$ for a sequence of real numbers and for the Dirac delta, which is awful. In what you wrote, $\delta_0$ is [the Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), not the first real number of your sequence.

Comment: @user1952009 2. In my integral I have $\delta_j^{-n}$ you have $a_j^{-1}$ -- but changing 1 to n doesn't change the conclusion, right? 3. Where does the last inequality you write come from? 4. In general, is there some requirement for distributions and test functions to have compact support?

Comment: $n = 1$ because I'm in $\mathbb{R}$ (you took the example $\phi(x) = e^{1/(x^2-1)}1_{|x| < 1}$ which is a test function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$). A test function is by definition $C^\infty$ with a compact support ($C^\infty_c$). The support of a distribution isn't the problem here, and it doesn't have to be compact (for example the Dirac comb $\Pi \text{I}(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-n)$ is a distribution)

Comment: @user1952009 And finally: where did $|\psi(x) - \psi(0)|<M|x|$ come from? (btw thanks - was very helpful)

Comment: $\psi(x)$ is differentiable (see also the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity a weaker assumption)